# In android application, i got json data successfully but i need only string

Tags: android, json

I got Json data like this

{:notice=>"Successful Login"}

The above message is showing in my emulator display but i need to show only "Successful Login".

Please help me out. I am new in android development.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: what you have tried?

Comment: I tried json parsing.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

```
String notice=jsondata.getString(":notice");
```

Comment: Already i have tried this but the thing is if json data have {notice:"Successful Login"} then it will work what i need. But i am getting {:notice=>"Successful Login"}. Only because of "=>" symbol i am getting nothing.